# Save classes in List and read them

Tags: java, list, class

So I would like to code a task managaer as a fun coding project but I'm stuck.

The basic idea is that I can create tasks with the following class

```
public Task(int id, String title, String description, LocalDate dueDate, boolean status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.status = false;
    }
```

Then I would like to add the task to a list and save the data to a text file.

Now, my problem is that when I add a task to the List and try to read it I get this output "Task@1ddc4ec2".

I'm not sure if it's even possible to save a class in a list like this but I don't know how else I'm supposed to do it.
I'd be happy to hear your ideas also. :D

I created a task with this code

```
tm.addTask(new Task(1, "First Try",
                  "My first try to add a task",
                   LocalDate.now(), false));

tm.addTask(new Task(2, "Second add",
                  "The second task I'm adding.",
                   LocalDate.now(), false));
```

and tried printing it with this one

```
System.out.println("All tasks in the list: " + tm.tasks);
```

I have a seperate class TaskManager (tm) where the list "tasks" is located. I wanted to see every entry with every entered detail but got "All tasks in the list: [Task@9807454, Task@1ddc4ec2]" instead.

Comment: Did you forget to override `toString` method in `Task` class?

Comment: Btw you don't save _classes_, you save _instances_ of classes ^^

Comment: When writing the content to a file, you might employee a “converter” to take it from an Object to text (and back again). You might also consider making use of a JSON converter